# Regenerate dummy app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

Okay, somewhat into developing a plugin (first time), decided to install rspec, and in my haste deleted the test directory that contains the 'dummy' rails application.

Nothing important in the dummy, but how do I re-generate it? It's truly gone, didn't commit it and the trash can is empty.

```
starkers@ubuntu:~/rails4/my_plugin/spec$ rails new dummy --skip-unit-test

Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try generating a new *plugin* (in the rails4 directory not in the my_plugin directory) with, for example `rails plugin new scratch_plugin` and then copying the generated dummy rails application from there.

And maybe backup or commit your code so you don't do this with your actual work ;)